# file_get_contents not working in a dynamic js call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, asp.net

So, I have been given an admin built in php and I was asked to implement an already done admin built in aspx into the new one(changing the css and so), the thing is that i want to dynamically "insert" into the main admin structure which is made in php only the part that's gonna be run in aspx, I made a reserach and found out that the way to do it was using file_get_contents and yeah it works, the thing is that i want that to show after I click on a link so I put the f_g_c into a js function to do so, the thing is that it doesnt work, it doesnt insert anything, it does it outside a function, but inside it just won't

```
<li class="active">
<a id="solicitud"  href=""  > 
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
<span>Solicitudes</span>
<span class="label label-primary label-circle pull-right">2</span>
</a>
```

---

```
var li = document.getElementById('solicitud');
li.onclick = aparecer();
function aparecer() {
<?php 
   $hola= "./solicitudAAA.aspx";

?>
var lo = document.getElementById('container');
lo.innerHTML ="<?php echo file_get_contents($hola); ?>";
return false;
}
```

above there are the section of code or well the link i want to click so it shows the aspx and the second section of code is the actual script, i don't know what I'm doing wrong and why inside the scriptit won't work, thanks for your answers!

Comment: Try to check your error log? Do you get something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code has something to do with your link's href. A blank href in your anchor tag will refresh the page causing the onclick in your script to not work. How about adding the following:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="solicitud" onclick="aparecer();">
 <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
 <span>Solicitudes</span>
 <span class="label label-primary label-circle pull-right">2</span>
</a>
```

To make things easier, add the function to the onclick attribute of the anchor tag to call the function rather than coding it inside the script.

Since onclick attribute(that contains the calling of function) is added to the anchor tag, you can remove this in the script:

```
var li = document.getElementById('solicitud');
li.onclick = aparecer();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried  doing what you said, it won't do anything, it says that aparecer is not defined ... the thing is that in the way I have it I can appear an echo just printing hello, but f_g_c just won't work

Comment: Have you tried checking the path of your file if it's pointing to the right path? Have you also tried putting the path instead of the variable like lo.innerHTML ="<?php echo file_get_contents('./solicitudAAA.aspx'); ?>";?

Comment: yeah I have inserted directly the aspx into de div i want just as itis file_get_contents('./solicitudAAA.aspx'); and it shows, but when i put that into a function, it doesnt work it makes the page appear like this https://i.gyazo.com/4c2da506bc81d36669c556e5ca3bfe0f.png

Comment: " return false;} <~the cause of this is probably the syntax. Try checking if the quotes have partners